# Joining on optional

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 2 tables:

```
Table1 - Criteria
Office_ID  Bus_Stream  Bus_Criteria  Crit_Value
1          ABC         0             20
1          ABC         1             21
1          ABC         2             7
2          ABC         0             15
2          ABC         1             12
2          ABC         2             21
3          XYZ         1             17
3          XYZ         2             3


Table2 - Limit
Bus_Stream  GroupID  TypeID  SubgroupID  Bus_Limit
ABC         20       21      7           50
ABC         15       12      21          100
XYZ         99       17      3           120
```

I need to create a join that allows me to pull back:

```
Result
Bus_Stream  Office_ID  GroupID  TypeID  SubgroupID  Bus_Limit
ABC         1          20       21      7           50
ABC         2          15       12      21          100
XYZ         3          (null)   17      3           120
```

Essentially, I need to join Table1.Crit_Value based on the following:

```
Table1.Bus_Criteria   Table2
0                     GroupID
1                     TypeID
2                     SubGroupID
```

with the added complication that if one or two of the 0/1/2 values from Bus_Criteria is missing, the joins will still occur on the remaining criteria.

I have tried a number of combinations of AND/OR on the join to no avail.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Did you try `outer left join`?

Comment: *with the added complication that if the 0/1/2 value from Bus_Criteria is missing, the joins will still occur on the other 2 criteria.*: I don't understand. What other criteria are there?

Comment: perhaps you need to use a case statement on the join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be what you're after..  use a case statement on the join.

The problem here is your data in t2 isn't normalized, you could also unpivot the 3 data columns in t2 so the join is more natural.

```
SELECT T2.Bus_Stream, T1.Office_ID, T2.GroupID, T2.TypeID, T2.SubGroupId, T2.bus_Limit
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2
 on T1.Bus_Stream = T2.Bus_Stream
and T1.Crit_value = case when T1.Bus_Critiera = 0 then T2.GroupID
                         when T1.Bus_Critiera = 1 then T2.TypeID
                         when T1.Bus_Critiera = 2 then T2.SubGroupID
                    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this?

```
SELECT
t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON 
    t1.Bus_Stream = t2.Bus_Stream AND
    CASE
        WHEN t1.Bus_Criteria = 0 
            THEN t2.GroupID = t1.Crit_Value
        WHEN t1.Bus_Criteria = 1
            THEN t2.TypeID = t1.Crit_Value
        ELSE 
            t2.SubGroupID = t1.Crit_Value
    END
```